# Unable to get value from model in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, model-view-controller, model, object-reference

I am new in MVC environment and I just started upgrading a website.

**Problem**

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

**Explanation**

I have javascript function for a button in the view and I am trying to get a property value *CurrentPageNo* from the associated model as shown below.

```
        $('#pPrevious').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.blur();
            if (ShowBusy()) {
                getPageIndexChanging(@Model.CurrentPageNo-1);
            }
        });
```

I am referring to the model as below:

```
@code
    ViewBag.Title = "Home"
End Code

@ModelType HomeModel

@Using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "indexForm", .name = "indexForm"}))
    Try
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

etc...
```

When I put a breakpoint in the model it doesn't work.

What Am I doing wrong in this situation ?

Comment: It's difficult to say where with the snippet, you should also post Controller. If possible please share entire code.

Comment: The debugger provides information about exactly where the exception occurred for diagnostic purposes. You should use that information yourself and, if you still need help, provide that information to us.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to Get c# model data in your javascript code. 
Simply you can add the value in a text box that is hidden and get value with getElementById in your javascript code.